# For compact subspaces $C$ and $K$ of $X$ and $Y$, prove that for every open set $U$ of $X \times Y$, there exist open sets $V$ and $W$ with...

Tags: general-topology, compactness

> Let $C$ be a compact subspace of $X$ and let $K$ be a compact subspace
>   of $Y$ . Let $U$ be an open set in $X \times Y$ containing $C \times K$. Show that there
>   exist open subspaces $V$ of $X$ and $W$ of $Y$ with $$C \times K \subset V \times W \subset U.$$

Any open set $U$ in $X \times Y$ is of the form $V \times W$ with $V$ open in $X$ and $W$ open in $Y$. By definition, $C \times K \subset U$ implies that $C \subset V$ and $K \subset W$. Since I didn't use the compactness of $C$ and $K$, is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Yes, not every open set has the product form. Compactness is necessary here, consider the neighborhood $\{(x,y)\mid y<x\}$ of $(0,1]\times\{0\}$ in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: The open ball $\{ (x,y) : x^2+y^2 < 1\}$ is an open subset of $\Bbb{R}^2 = \Bbb{R}\times\Bbb{R}$, but it doesn't look like $V \times W$ with $V, W$ both open subsets of $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: This is called the *generalized tube lemma*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrect that every open set $U$ in $X\times Y$ is of the form $V\times W$ for some $X$-open $V$ and $Y$-open $W.$ Consider for example the open unit disk in the Euclidean plane.

What you *can* say, however, is that every such open set $U$ is a *union* of sets of that form--or put another way, sets of that form comprise a basis for the product topology on $X\times Y.$

For an outline of a proof, see [here](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tube_lemma).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just have one more question about my error. You say that $U$ is the union of sets of the form $V \times W$ where $V$ is open in $X$ and $W$ is open in $Y$, right? So $U = \cup^{\infty}_{i=1} (V_i \times W_i) = \cup^{\infty}_{i=1} V_i \times \cup^{\infty}_{i=1} W_i$, but we know that arbitrary unions of open sets are open, so $\cup^{\infty}_{i=1} V_i$ must be open in $X$ and $\cup^{\infty}_{i=1} W_i$ must be open in $Y$. What is wrong with that?

Comment: There are a few problems with that, actually. For one, $U$ needn't be a union of countably-many such sets $V\times W.$ For another, in general, while we have $$U=\bigcup_{i\in J}(V_i\times W_i)\subseteq\left(\bigcup_{i\in J}V_i\right)\times\left(\bigcup_{i\in J}W_i\right),$$ this inclusion may be strict ($J$ is some index set, here).